# IdentityServer4 with ASP.NET Core 2.1 Identity - Error loading external login information

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I'm trying to get IdentityServer4 get to work with ASP.NET Core Identity using my own UserStore for SSO. While the guides seem rather straightforward, and the authentication process itself seems to work, in the application (another ASP.NET Core MVC application) I get the following error:

`Error loading external login information`

My setup is as follows:

For the ASP.NET MVC application (the client):

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan =TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
})
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001/";

    options.ClientId = "clientId";
    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
    options.Scope.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile);
    options.Scope.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email);
    options.Scope.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess);

    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
});
```

For the IdentityServer4 application:

```
services.AddScoped<UserManager<User>, MyUserManager>();
services.AddIdentity<User, UserGroup>()
    .AddRoleStore<MyRoleStore>()
    .AddUserStore<MyUserStore>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Subject;
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name;
    options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role;
});

services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(OpenIDConfig.GetApiResources())
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(OpenIDConfig.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryClients(OpenIDConfig.GetClients())
    .AddResourceOwnerValidator<ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator<User>>()
    .AddProfileService<ProfileService<User>>();
```

The main issue is that I don't know where to even start looking for why there is a problem with this after a successful authentication flow.

Comment: Can you add the code of the ProfileService? That's where I would start to look.

Comment: `ProfileService<T>` is part of IdentityServer4

Comment: Can you disable `options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint` flag in MVC client and try whether it works? As previous @RuardvanElburg mentioned most probably there's a issue with ProfileService implementation in IdentityServer.

Comment: @DanielRusznyak I have basically the same issue, using Google as an external identity provider. Have you been able to solve it?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Not for IS4, but I've found a similar issue with Google and the problem was that on certain platforms and in certain browsers, you have to disable SameSite for external cookies, since "Lax" isn't properly supported.
`services.ConfigureExternalCookie(options => { options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None; });`

Comment: @DanielRusznyak in fact the problem was that I was changing the default `SignInScheme` in the Google options. It *has* to be `IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme`, because that's what `SignInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync` uses.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque thank you. I was following IDS$ docs (https://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/4_external_authentication.html) and there they use `options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;` which does not work. Your option however does!

Answer (score 6):

Since it does help me - but I've almost missed anserw which was in comment I'll put it here. Comment is made by @Thomas Levesque and you might thank him for that ansertw ;-)

> in fact the problem was that I was changing the default SignInScheme
>   in the Google options. It has to be IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme,
>   because that's what SignInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync uses.